# Adding all values selected from the Listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, double, average

So this is how far I have gotten I am not really sure.
So I populated my listbox1 with values  such as 1.2, 1.3
So how do I add all the selected values of my listbox and caculate the average?
If you could help me I be very thankful.

```
    List<double> doubleList = new List<double>();
    private void btnGetAverage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make the SelectionMode property of your listbox as MultiSimple. Then try this code.

```
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        total += Double.Parse(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString());
    }

    MessageBox.Show("The average is: " + total / listBox1.SelectedItems.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you the Average method:

```
List<double> doubleList = new List<double>();
private void btnGetAverage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
       var myList = listbox1.SelectedItems as List<double>;
       return myList.Average();
    }
}
```

Comment: there is an error at listbox1 does nto exist in current context and return has error

Comment: I was assuming you have access to listbox1 in your code behind as you were already checking for SelectedIndex in your code sample. am i wrong?

Comment: I just added the values directly into the listBox1 because I didnt know how to convert them to double and waning to calculate them from in there

Answer (score 0):

Add your list of doubles to your `ListBox` like this:

```
listBox1.DataSource = doubleList;
```

Then this will get you the average of only selected items:

```
var average = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<double>().Average();
```

Comment: Your code breaks when running it after selecting the values from the listbox

Comment: Breaks how? It works fine when I test it. Also, how is it that `listBox1` doesn't exist (reading your comment to Yuval)? You posted it in your own code, and you didn't say that part was throwing an error.

Comment: InvalidCastException it says for yours. No the code I posted didnt throw an error the listbox1 inside the code he posted was throwing an error.